# QSignalMapper (in PyQt5) not working when the function argument is a str

Tags: python, pyqt5

I try to migrate my code from pyqt4 to pyqt5 and I have trouble dealing with QSignalMapper.

When I'm doing a mapping and that the argument passed to the function is an int, everything works just fine, but when it is a string, nothing happen.

The code below returns no error, but just the `act_int.trigger()` behaves correctly, and not `act_str.trigger()`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtWidgets,QtCore

def a_function(x):
    print("x : ",x)
act_int = QtWidgets.QAction()
act_str = QtWidgets.QAction()

mapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper()
act_int.triggered.connect(mapper.map)
mapper.setMapping(act_int,1)
act_str.triggered.connect(mapper.map)
mapper.setMapping(act_str,"a_string")
mapper.mapped.connect(a_function)

act_int.trigger()
act_str.trigger()
```

Prints only:

```
x :  1
```

As I would expect it prints:

```
x :  1
x :  a_string
```

Maybe I'm not using QSignalMapper properly (I did not find examples with pyqt5 online)

Comment: The [mapped signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html#signals) is overloaded. So add this line: `mapper.mapped[str].connect(a_function)`.

Comment: Yes you right!  I did not knew that you could specify the type of the connection function argument as an item of QSignalMapper.mapped . Thanks !

Comment: There is an example on the PyQt wiki that shows how to use int/str values: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Using%20a%20signal%20mapper

Comment: @NZD Thanks, but the example you give is for PyQT4. I was interested in PyQT5 solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should overload the right method:

```
mapped.mapped[str].connect(a_function)
```